# Getting error while calling one sendOTP API using PHP

Tags: php

I am getting  error while calling one API using PHP.

Error:

```
Warning: include(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/otp.php on line 8

Warning: include(http://api.msg91.com/api/sendotp.php?authkey="15529*************"&mobile="9937229853"&message="Your verification code is:1111"&sender="Subhrajyoti"&otp="1111"): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/otp.php on line 8

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'http://api.msg91.com/api/sendotp.php?authkey="15529*************"&mobile="9937229853"&message="Your verification code is:1111"&sender="Subhrajyoti"&otp="1111"' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/otp.php on line 8
```

Here is my code:

```
$authkey="15529*************";
$mobile=9937229853;
$code=1111;
$message="Your verification code is:".$code;
$sender="Subhrajyoti";
$otp=1111;
include ('http://api.msg91.com/api/sendotp.php?authkey="'.$authkey.'"&mobile="'.$mobile.'"&message="'.$message.'"&sender="'.$sender.'"&otp="'.$otp.'"');
```

Here I am trying to send OTP but getting those message. Here I need to send OTP and get the response.

Comment: i dont understand why are including this?you can use curl

Comment: This `url` is only API to send the OTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `CURL` or `file_get_contents`.

```
$response = file_get_contents('http://api.msg91.com/api/sendotp.php?authkey="'.$authkey.'"&mobile="'.$mobile.'"&message="'.$message.'"&sender="'.$sender.'"&otp="'.$otp.'"');
$response = json_decode($response);
```

or
using cURL:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$data=array('authkey'=>$authkey,'mobile'=>$mobile,'message'=>$message);//all parameter
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://api.msg91.com/api/sendotp.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($result);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: I used `file_get_contents.` now i am getting message `{"message":"OTP should be numeric","type":"error"}`.Here I am passing otp as numeric.

Comment: just check the url and parameters..file_get_contents will execute url and get back with file content or response

Comment: just make sure if there is any space in url parameters to avoid this issues  you need to use `urlencode()`

Comment: glad to help @satya

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this line:

```
include ('http://api.msg91.com/api/sendotp.php?authkey="'.$authkey.'"&mobile="'.$mobile.'"&message="'.$message.'"&sender="'.$sender.'"&otp="'.$otp.'"');
```

use `cURL` to hit the url appended with the message and mobile number and get the response from it. And don't forget to encode the entire url by using `urlencode()` function.

Ex:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$APIresponse = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$res = json_decode($APIresponse, true);
```

Comment: Can you please share your idea i am little bit confused.

Comment: what this `$postData` contains.

Comment: Just check the updated answer, it's easy to implement.